# perl : how to get status and outputs for linux command (such as bjobs)

Tags: perl, system

I use perl to check the status of LSF (`bjobs -w`).

Howeven, sometime the system of LSF will fail.
(show "Failed in an LSF library call: Failed in sending/receiving a message: Connection reset by peer" in screen)

I need check

1. LSF fail or not (currently, the output of bjobs -w is none)
2. if LSF is OK, check the output.

Unfortunately, LSF will fail by random.
So I can exec one time "bjobs -w" and check the result/status.

I use :

```
$nstat = `bjobs -w`;
```

It can check the status of LSF. If LSF fail, the `$nstat` is none, the result equal with all bjobs done.

```
$nstat = system(bjobs -w);
```

It can't save the result with LSF is OK.

Would you mind give me some suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

`system` sets and returns `$?`. `$?` is set by `readpipe` (backticks) in exactly the same way.

```perl
my $output = `bjobs -w`;
die( "Couldn't run bjobs: $!\n"                         if $? == -1;
die( "bjobs was killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F )."\n" ) if $? & 0x7F;
die( "bjobs exited with error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n" )      if $? >> 8;
print( "bjobs was successful. Output:\n$output" );
```